# What are some valid cursor uses?

Tags: cursor, rdbms

**Short version**

What are some (real) valid use cases of cursors?

**Long version**

A while ago, when I was in my database class and the teacher touched the cursors topic, I asked her about valid use cases. She answered with an use of cursors for presentation purposes: you have a book database and you want to show all the books but "grouped" by author, and only showing the author's name once.
I am not convinced by this example because it seems to me that these kind of presentation concerns do not belong to the database but the client (a UI that shows them in a pretty way).

I have thought about valid use cases for cursors, but I can't find any that I can't express in a clearer way with no cursors. It seems to me that using cursors makes you think in a "imperative way" rather than the "declarative, set-based" way you should think most of the time.

So I would like to know when it's good to use cursors. I would prefer to hear about real use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you should go out of your way to avoid cursors, and try to use set-based standard SQL when you can.

One case where it is actually *required* is if you want to return multiple results in one query with PostgreSQL.

```
CREATE FUNCTION myfunc(refcursor, refcursor) RETURNS SETOF refcursor AS $$
BEGIN
    OPEN $1 FOR SELECT * FROM table_1;
    RETURN NEXT $1;
    OPEN $2 FOR SELECT * FROM table_2;
    RETURN NEXT $2;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: What about using UNION in that case? I know it won't work if the columns of both tables are not compatible (same number and compatible types), but if that's the case, what would be the use of such query?

Comment: @DanielCastro Yes you should UNION if the columns are the same. But let's say you wanted to return all of the data for a web page in a single database call. Example, the question, answers, comments. You couldn't union those. In other databases like SQL Server you can return multiple result sets without a cursor.

Comment: In that case, how would you distinguish question rows from answer rows, for example? Even then, I would think the right way is to just make a backup. Anyway, you say that's the case of PostgreSQL. What about SQL Server? If you can do this without cursors, why do cursors exist in SQL Server?

Comment: You can see how you would call it here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-cursors.html . I can't think of a good reason in SQL Server, but I did give you a good reason in Postgres.

Comment: Well, now I understand that. Thanks for your answer.
I'll wait to see if someone comes with more examples to choose the answer. Anyway, I upvoted your answer